# Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)

Tags: python, wxpython, exit

I'm trying to figure out what this message means

> Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)

I'm making an application using wxpython. The whole thing is a chat so there are a few Classes I made in this code example.

Under conditions I'll specify bellow the program stops and returns that exit code.

This code is supposed to represent a graphic presentation of a single chat room (it's contained within a wx.Frame that has other panels as well)

```
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
from messages.Message import Message
from messages.Message1 import Message1
from messages.Message2 import Message2
from messages.Message3 import Message3
from user import User
from Room import Room


class RoomGraph:
    def __init__(self, parent, room: Room, width, height, user: User):
        self.room = room
        self.size = (width, height)
        self.tp = TitlePan(parent, room.name, width, height)
        self.mb = MessageBoard(parent, width, height)
        self.ip = InputPan(self, parent, room.id, user, width, height)
        self.Hide()

    def sent_msg(self, m):
        self.mb.sent_msg(m)

    def recv_msg(self, m):
        self.mb.recived_msg(m)

    def Show(self):
        self.tp.Show()
        self.mb.Show()
        self.ip.Show()

    def Hide(self):
        self.tp.Hide()
        self.mb.Hide()
        self.ip.Hide()

    def change_name(self, name):
        self.tp.change_name(name)


class TitlePan(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, width, height):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(width, height / 10), pos=(0, 0))
        # print(f'size title={(width / 10, height / 10)}')
        self.title = wx.StaticText(self, label=name)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.AddSpacer(500)
        sizer.Add(self.title, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def change_name(self, name):
        self.title.SetLabel(name)


class MessageBoard(wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent, width, height):
        wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, -1, size=(width, height / 10 * 7),
                                                    pos=(0, height / 10),
                                                    style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def sent_msg(self, m: Message):
        msg = wx.StaticText(self, label=m.__str__())
        msg.SetBackgroundColour('green')
        self.sizer.Add(msg, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 5)

    def recived_msg(self, m: Message):
        msg = wx.StaticText(self, label=m.__str__())
        msg.SetBackgroundColour('grey')
        self.sizer.Add(msg, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)


class InputPan(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, room_graph: RoomGraph, parent, id, user: User, width, height):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(width, height / 10 * 2), pos=(0, height / 10 * 8))
        self.id = id
        self.user = user
        self.room_graph = room_graph

        self.inp = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        txt = wx.StaticText(self, label='show up you asshole')
        sen = wx.Button(self, label='send')
        sen.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.send_msg)
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        hori = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hori.Add(self.inp, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)
        hori.Add(txt, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)
        hori.Add(sen, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        main_sizer.Add(hori, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 5)
        self.Layout()

    def send_msg(self, e):
        txt = self.inp.GetValue()
        m = Message1(self.id, self.user.id, txt)
        m.send(self.user)
        self.room_graph.sent_msg(m)
```

that exit occurs specifically when a room is displayed (these three panels)and I go to a diffrent tab (outside of the wx.python application). If I tab out for a while (20 seconds or so) the program 'exists' with that code.

It doesn't happen if I'm currently showing any other wx.Panel nor if I don't leave the wx.frame (tab out).

the same exit also occurs when I press the sen wx.Button in the InputPan. But it doesn't seem to actually activate the send_msg function (It didn't print anything when I put a print in it's first line). it freezes for a bit then exists without raising an exception.

it also exists when I press a button that isn't bound to a function

I haven't been able to find anything about it.
help?

this is Python 3.7.4 if that's relevant

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (see this [code of a wxPython application](https://pastebin.com/pn86mFiK)). There is lots of code here, but imported classes missing